# How to use the CFMutableArrray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-foundation, cftypes

I am reading a video file using AVFoundation framework and getting the image buffers as CMSampleBuferRef, I added the buffers in CFMutableArrayRef using CFArrayAppendValue() function.

But If I want to retrieve from that array, Is there any way?

Apple document for [CFMutableArrayRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/Reference/reference.html) gives no method to retrive from array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using the APIs Matt pointed out (+1), `CFMutableArray` is toll-free-bridged with `NSMutableArray`. you can simply cast an instance of a `CFMutableArray` to an `NSMutableArray` and use `NSMutableArray`'s methods (or the other way around). Following the cast to `NSMutableArray`, you can use `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`.

Many Foundation types have CoreFoundation counterparts which are toll free bridged. As a toll free bridged type, the cast does not introduce a promotion or conversion. Think of them as the same type, and that instances may be converted/cast to their CF-NS counterparts without introducing overhead or change to the instance. Technically, implicit reference counting may be introduced if your implementation uses NS-types rather than CF-types under ARC.

This may be useful if you are writing in ObjC, and are more familiar with the ObjC APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the CFArray function `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex`, or something similar. CFMutableArray's "inherit" from CFArrays, and the documentation on CFMutableArray only contains the API that differs from CFArray.

See the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001192).